# Populating spinner with Retrofit Json

Tags: android, json, list, spinner, retrofit

I have to populate a list of timezone from API Json response. I am new in android here and searched many of codes but none works for me. I have this response and using Rerofit 1.9 to access it. I don't want to create an extra POJO class for this and just want to get the list and add it to the list to show in the spinner. Other examples have other class and mapped the array for the result. Is there a simple way to do this. My response code looks like.

```
{"status": {
"response_code": 0
"response_message": "OK"
"response_extra": nul
}-
"data": {
"Timezone": [416]
0:  {
"code": "Africa/Abidjan"
"title": "Africa/Abidjan"
}-
1:  {
"code": "Africa/Accra"
"title": "Africa/Accra"
}-
2:  {
"code": "Africa/Addis_Ababa"
"title": "Africa/Addis_Ababa"
}-
3:  {
"code": "Africa/Algiers"
"title": "Africa/Algiers"
}
-...
-....
-....
-...
-...
}
}
```

Comment: If you are using retrofit you must use POJO class as retro fit automatically parses json for you, you donot need to parse data in retrofit. else you could use volley if if do not wish to create pojo class

Comment: I already have parsed the code but what i cannot do is add it to the list to show in the spinner adapter

Comment: JsonObject data=response.getAsJsonObject("data");
 JsonArray timezones=data.getAsJsonArray("Timezone");
 for(int i=0;i<timezones.size();i++)
  {
 JsonObject  timezone=timezones.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
String timecode = timezone.getAsJsonPrimitive("title").getAsString();
 Log.e("timezone array", timecode);
  timezonelist.add(timecode);
}
 }

  }

Comment: can you add the code you have used for adding the list to the spinner